# Loading a PNG using SDL2 + SDL2Image using C++ and cmake on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, sdl-2

I'm working on a simple tutorial from here: https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/index.php

My initial program did not do any image loading. It just showed a screen and went away. Everything worked fine. Here is my initial `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(01_hello_world)


set(CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(hello 01_hello_SDL.cpp)
target_include_directories(hello PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hello ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Everything worked and compiled just fine. However, I then wanted to load a PNG image, which I thought would be a very easy. Googling led me to the SDL2 Image library, and the `IMG_Load` method. So I went ahead and installed `libsdl2-image-dev`, and my `CMakeLists.txt` file grew by two more lines::

```
set(SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.a")
```

However, just by using the `IMG_Load` method, the make command threw a whole bunch of library requirements: `libtiff-dev`, `libpng-dev`, `libjpeg-dev`, `libwebp-dev`. All this just to load a png file! So I went ahead and installed all those, and now my `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this abomination (I used `find_package` where I could, and manually set variables where I couldn't):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(01_hello_world)

set(CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
find_package(JPEG REQUIRED)
find_package(TIFF REQUIRED)

set(SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.a")
set(WEBP_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.a")

add_executable(hello 01_hello_SDL.cpp)
target_include_directories(hello PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hello ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES} ${PNG_LIBRARY} ${JPEG_LIBRARY} ${WEBP_LIBRARIES} ${TIFF_LIBRARIES} Threads::Threads)
```

At this point, when I make, I get this error:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable hello
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l{TIFF_LIBRARIES}
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target 'hello' failed
make[2]: *** [hello] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've been googling for hours. Can someone provide a light in this darkness?

Also is this the correct approach to working with sdl + cmake?

Comment: The important part of the error message is `cannot find -l{TIFF_LIBRARIES}`. It seems you are missing the `$` in `${TIFF_LIBRARIES}`. Are you sure the `CMakeLists.txt` file you show is correct and the one you're using? What happens if you try again after rerunning `cmake` to regenerate the build files using the `CMakeLists.txt` file you currently show?

Comment: And instead of `${TIFF_LIBRARIES}` I suggest you use the imported target `TIFF::TIFF` (mentioned in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindTIFF.html)). You should change from using the variables to using the imported targets for *all* your libraries.

Comment: When I use `TIFF:TIFF` in place of `${TIFF_LIBRARIES}`, I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lTIFF:TIFF`. Edit: Oh, ok. I missed a semicolon. I nuked the build folder and did the whole cmake + make and now it's fine. What a rollercoaster.

Comment: PS using "JPEG::JPEG" instead of "${JPEG_LIBRARIES}" doesn't work. The `cmake` command yields an error about the target not being found. The page you linked by the way, I have visited it many times but I have no idea what `FindTIFF` actually is. Is it a method? How do I invoke it? How is it related to `find_package`?? Not very obvious.

Comment: Please read [the CMake module list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html). There you can find the [`FindTIFF`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindTIFF.html) module, as well as the [`FindJPEG`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJPEG.html) module (which says it creates the `JPEG::JPEG` target).

Answer (score 0):

```
set(SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.a")
```

It seems like you aren't dynamically linking SDL2_image to your program.
I don't know how to change it in CMake,but you could compile your program utilizing this pattern:

```
g++ your_program.cpp -o your_program -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

You may also utilize a Makefile like this one:

```
OBJS = your_program.cpp

OBJ_NAME = your_program_output

all:
    g++ $(OBJS) -o $(OBJ_NAME) -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image # don't forget about replacing the four spaces by a tab character
```

One last thing, lazy foo has a tutorial teaching how to install and set up the SDL2_image library on linux utilizing an IDE (Code::Blocks) or not (command lines and Makefiles).
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/linux/index.php